# How to disable the toolbar of a declared Gutenberg InnerBlock element in a template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to design a custom Gutenberg block using InnerBlocks with a template. I want to disable each control in the toolbar of a '**paragraph**' innerblock in that template. I have searching but I didn't find a solution.
Maybe it's more understandable with this code:

```
edit: function( props ) {
    return el('div',{className: props.className},
        el( InnerBlocks,{
            template:[
                [ 'core/image', {} ],
                [ 'core/heading', { placeholder: 'Book Title' } ],
                [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Summary' },
                    /*  
                        I want to disable the toolbar of this innerblock
                        Of course the below code is not possible into a template of innerblocks
                        [BlockControls,{ key: 'controls' }, []],
                    */
                ]
            ],
            templateLock: "all",
        })
    );
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not yet possible; at this time, you can only add additional controls for existing blocks, you cannot remove them. This has been requested at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23619